# draw2d.js : connected event

Tags: javascript, draw2d-js

How to get know what two figures was conneted in draw2d js libdrary ( http://www.draw2d.org/draw2d/ )?
I cant find corresponding event/callback method..

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, found: stackChanged method of CommandStack, with one argument event, with command.label="Connecting Ports", make sure you catching postExecute event.

Comment: Thanks for bothering to come back and add this detail

Comment: Can you add an example, please?

Comment: Hello, @GeorgiG. This was so long ago that I do not have that code :) Draw2d js has changed a lot from that time I think. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to figure it out on my own, thanks to the public source.